# Restful Web services with java_web_app and json

Tags: java, rest, web

i create a restful web service using entities classes from database:

---

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cjg3Z.png)

and this is my web.xml

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LcMm.png)
It works with xml data but not with json. How to enable json data return?

Comment: dont display linked picture. please provide your code HERE!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add dependencies for JSON support in the POM.xml such as jackson json jar [OR] add the jackson json jar to project build path and WEB-INF/lib folder.